# Having trouble with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, modeling

I'm trying to plot the solutions to the following set of differential equations,

[image: System of Differential Equations]

I'm doing this through NDSolve with the following code,

```
b = 0.01;
dh = 0.05;
dm = 2;
g = 0.9;
s = NDSolve[{
   sh'[t] == -b*sh[t]*im[t] + dh*(1 - sh[t]),
   ih'[t] == b*sh[t]*im[t] - (g + dh)*ih[t],
   rh'[t] == g*ih[t] - dh*rh[t],
   sm'[t] == -b*sm[t]*ih[t] + dm*(1 - sm[t]),
   im'[t] == b*sm[t]*ih[t] + dm*im[t],
   ih[0] == 0.001, im[0] == 0.001, rh[0] == 0, sh[0] == 0.999, 
   sm[0] == 0.999}, {sh, ih, rh, sm, im}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

However I get an error out the other end, namely this, [image]

and I'm not entirely sure what's wrong, I've followed the general format on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html, and I've tried making the variables and parameters single letters but nothing has worked.

Any help with be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have `sm[0]=0.999` should it be `==`?

Comment: BTW, it looks like you have a `+` in the `im'[t]` equation where there should be a `-`.

Comment: @Anthony P You can  directly add tex code for Eqs. in forum!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Clear`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) any old definitions.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

b = 0.01;
dh = 0.05;
dm = 2;
g = 0.9;
s = NDSolve[{sh'[t] == -b*sh[t]*im[t] + dh*(1 - sh[t]), 
    ih'[t] == b*sh[t]*im[t] - (g + dh)*ih[t], rh'[t] == g*ih[t] - dh*rh[t], 
    sm'[t] == -b*sm[t]*ih[t] + dm*(1 - sm[t]), 
    im'[t] == b*sm[t]*ih[t] + dm*im[t], ih[0] == 0.001, im[0] == 0.001, 
    rh[0] == 0, sh[0] == 0.999, sm[0] == 0.999}, {sh, ih, rh, sm, im}, {t, 0, 
    20}];

Plot[
 Evaluate[(#[t] & /@ {sh, ih, rh, sm, im}) /. s], {t, 0, 20},
 PlotLegends -> {sh, ih, rh, sm, im}]
```

[image]